# open notification sound not working but notification coming

Tags: objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am trying local notification with sound in objective c code but i cant be able to get sound. My notification is coming but sound not working.

```
UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;

UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings =
[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (localNotif == nil)
    return;

localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

localNotif.alertBody=msg;
localNotif.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"View Details", nil);
localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
//localNotif.soundName=@"sound.caf";
localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```

Comment: is your iphone on silent mode :P

Comment: no my iphone is not in silent mode.

Comment: then go in setting and check whether sound is ON or not for push of your app...

Answer (score 0):

Generally this issue occurs because of sound file may not be added to target bundle resources.

```
Select project file--> Target--> Build phases--> Copy bundle resources
```

Then add your sound file if it's not listed.
The sound file should be in allowed format (.caf,.aiff etc..)